# How to augment a QASM circuit for orbital rotation

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qasm

1. Could anyone advise on how to properly augment the hamiltonian circuits in https://github.com/CQCL/ethz-hackathon22/tree/main/benchmarking/circuits for orbital rotation ?  https://poe.com/s/nPhqBSsg27Zu6MHzvO7s is a bit confusing to me.
2. Does any orbital rotated Hamiltonian have a Hartree-Fock state `|00001111>` ?
3. Why isn't the state `|11110000>` considered as the Hartree-Fock state for the given Hamiltonian, even though this state is the Hartree-Fock state for the original Fermi-Hubbard Model?

For more context, see https://github.com/QunaSys/quantum-algorithm-grand-challenge#fermi-hubbard-model-

`The orbital rotation means linear transformation of the creation operator and annihilation operator`

But I am not sure about the rest of the paragraph after this quoted sentence just above

now looking at https://github.com/buttercutter/quantum-climate-challenge-2023/blob/main/notebooks/vqe_co2.ipynb (search for `fh = get_fermion_operator(mh)` inside the notebook) , it may actually gives some ideas on how to perform orbital rotation ?